# Serializing a tree in Play for Scala

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have the following class that's a tree node:

```
case class Node[A] ( id: Int, data: A, var children: Option[Seq[Node[A]]],
                        var parent: Option[Node[A]] )
```

where id is the node id number, data represents information stored in the node, children is the list of children nodes, and parent is the parent node.

I want to generate a json with the tree, so I wrote the following implicit val:

```
implicit val nodeWrite : Writes[Node[Data]] = (
      (JsPath \ "sk").write[Int] and
      (JsPath \ "dat").write[Data] and
      (JsPath \ "ch").write[Option[Seq[Node[Data]]]] and
      (JsPath \ "par").write[Option[Node[Data]]]
  ) (unlift(Node[Data].unapply))
```

However the compiler complains:

> missing argument list for method apply in object Node Unapplied
>   methods are only converted to functions when a function type is
>   expected. You can make this conversion explicit by writing apply _ or
>   apply(*,*,*,*) instead of apply.

How to fix this?

**UPDATE**

Data is defined as:

```
case class Data (descrip: String)
```

**UPDATE 2**

Since I needed a tree with N roots, I created a Tree class containing a sequence of nodes.

```
case class Tree[A] ( var nodes: Option[Seq[Node[A]]] )
```

However I have a problem with serializing the tree:

```
  implicit val treeWrite : Writes[Tree[Data]] = new Writes[Tree[Data]] {
    def writes(x: Tree[Data]) = {
      Json.obj(
        "nodes" -> x.nodes.map(_.map(n => writes(n)))
        )
    }
  }
```

it throws

> type mismatch; found : Option[Nothing] required:
>   play.api.libs.json.Json.JsValueWrapper

in the `x.nodes.map` line.

Comment: What is `Data` and how did you compile `Node[Data].unapply` ?

Comment: Take a look at the update. I couldn't compile the Writes object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have complete answer, but you can help compiler by specifying types:

```
(unlift[Node[Data],(Int, Data, Option[Seq[Node[Data]]], Option[Node[Data]])]
  (Node.unapply[Data](_)))
```

But it doesn't help you, since you have to use recursive types with `lazyWrite`. I would suggest use here more explicit approach:

```
implicit val nodeWrite : Writes[Node[Data]] = new Writes[Node[Data]] {
  def writes(x: Node[Data]) = {
    Json.obj(
      "id" -> x.id,
      "data" -> x.data,
      "children" -> x.children.map(_.map(n => writes(n))),
      "parent" -> x.parent.map(n => writes(n)))
  }
}
val child = Node(1, "child", None, None)
val node = Node(1, "data", Some(List(child)), None)

Json toJson node
res0: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = {"id":1,"data":"data",
   "children":[{"id":1,"data":"child","children":null,"parent":null}],"parent":null}
```

Add null handling and you will be fine.

Comment: I have accepted your answer, but I still have an issue, can you take a look at Update 2? thanks!

Comment: @ps0604 in your update you use the wrong writes. Try this one: `"nodes" -> x.nodes.map(_.map(n => nodeWrite.writes(n)))` because your tree is constructed not from tree but from nodes.